# Trying to run sql query to populate several dataframes but getting empty dfs

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle

I have an sql query that I need to run separately for different time periods. I want to run it in a loop and populate all dataframes. If I run queries one-by-one it works fine, but the loop outputs a whole bunch of empty dfs.

```py
conn = pyodbc.connect("my connection details")

# time periods
may_jun_19 = [dt.date(day=1, month=5, year=2019), dt.date(day=1, month=7, year=2019)]
jul_19 = [dt.date(day=1, month=7, year=2019), dt.date(day=1, month=8, year=2019)]
aug_nov_19 = [dt.date(day=1, month=8, year=2019), dt.date(day=1, month=12, year=2019)]
dec_19 = [dt.date(day=1, month=12, year=2019), dt.date(day=1, month=1, year=2020)]
jan_feb_20 = [dt.date(day=1, month=1, year=2020), dt.date(day=1, month=3, year=2020)]
mar_may_20 = [dt.date(day=1, month=3, year=2020), dt.date(day=20, month=5, year=2020)]

months = [may_jun_19, jul_19, aug_nov_19, dec_19, jan_feb_20, mar_may_20]

# Initialise empty dataframes and put them in a list
mj19 = j19 = an19 = d19 = jf20 = mm20 = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = [mj19, j19, an19, d19, jf20, mm20]

# Run a query under a for cycle
for df, month in zip(dfs, months):
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=month)
```

If I run this code I get one dataframe with data called df, even though I never initialised this name, and a whole bunch of empty dataframes.

This is the query I'm trying to run:

```sql
 query = """select source_location,
                  dest_location,
                  sum(best_tonnes)
           from mq2.v_movement_summary 
           where start_time >= ? and 
                  end_time < ? and
                  source_location = '18_TO_JB CRUSH' or
                  source_location like 'AP11%' and
                  mine_site_code = 'JB' and 
                  type = 'Movement'
           group by source_location,
                    dest_location"""
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A. This does not work the way you intend it to:**

```
# Initialise empty dataframes and put them in a list
mj19 = j19 = an19 = d19 = jf20 = mm20 = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = [mj19, j19, an19, d19, jf20, mm20]
```

You are creating 6 references to the same empty data-frame and putting them in a list you never use again.

**B. This does nothing, well kind of;**

```
# Run a query under a for cycle
for df, month in zip(dfs, months):
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=month)
```

You create a data-frame from your query. And that's it. The end.
The `df` variable is getting overwritten at every "cycle" and you are left with the last data-frame of the loop.

**C. Solution;**

```
# ... your time periods ...

months = [may_jun_19, jul_19, aug_nov_19, dec_19, jan_feb_20, mar_may_20]

# initialize an empty list
list_ = []

# run your queries
for df, month in zip(dfs, months):
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=month)

    # append the df created by your query to the list
    list_.append(df)
```

Now you have a list of data-frames.

Comment: Thanks! I have just figured it out as well. I'm now initialising just a list of period names `dfs = ['mj19', 'j19', 'an19', 'd19', 'jf20', 'mm20']` and an empty dict (results) instead of list of dataframes. And then under `for` cycle I do: `results[df] = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=month)`